# How set unnecessary field in django form?

Tags: python, django, web, django-forms

```
class RequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Online request.
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = ["language", "daytime", "daysofweek", "phone", "email", "name"]
        widgets = {
                'language': forms.Select(),
                'daytime': RadioSelectNotNull(),
                'daysofweek': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
       }
```

How to install the obligatory filling one of the two fields, 'phone' or 'email'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set on the **model** fields `blank=false`, `null=false`, the ModelForm will treat it as required. These are set to `False` by default.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but if the intent is to require that at least one of `phone` or `email` be non-blank, use a custom `clean` method to do that:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
    if not (cleaned_data.get('phone') or cleaned_data.get('email')):
        raise ValidationError('At least one of phone or email is required.')
    return cleaned_data
```